# Questions about Celery

Tags: celery

I'm trying to learn what Celery is & does and I've gone through some basic tutorials like [first steps with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) and [this](http://hairycode.org/2013/07/23/first-steps-with-celery-how-to-not-trip/) one, and I have a few questions about Celery:

In the (first steps) tutorial, you start a Celery worker and then you can basically just open an interpreter & call the task defined as:

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> add.delay(4, 4)
```

So my questions are:

1. What's happening here? add() is a method that we wrote in the tasks file and we're calling add.delay(4,4). So we're calling a method over a method!?
2. How does this work? How does the 'delay' method get added to 'add'?
3. Does the Celery worker do the work of adding 4+4? As opposed to the work being done by the caller of that method? - like it would have been if I had just defined a method called add in the interpreter and just executed

   add(4,4)
4. If the answer to 3 is yes, then how does Celery know it has to do some work? All we're doing is - importing a method from the module we wrote and call that method. How does control get passed to the Celery worker?

Also, while answering #4, it'd also be great if you could tell me how you know this. I'd be very curious to know if these things are documented somewhere that I'm missing/failing to understand it, and how I could have known the answer. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Hint: the tiny little `@app.task` decorator is responsible for the magic. If you look into what decorators are, it should become rather apparent.

Comment: I @app.task does some magic, I'm just trying to understand what the magic is. Edit: Ok, I need to read up on decorators. I'll do that

Comment: Cool, thanks! BTW, that still doesn't answer 3 & 4

Comment: The answer to 4 is the celery is receiving a message from a broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's happening here? `add()` is a method that we wrote in the tasks file and we're calling `add.delay(4,4)`. So we're calling a method over a method!?

Everything is an object in Python. Everything has properties. Functions/methods also have properties. For example:

```
def foo(): pass
print(foo.__name__)
```

This is nothing special syntax-wise.

> How does this work? How does the `delay` method get added to `add`?

The `@app.task` *decorator* does that.

> Does the Celery worker do the work of adding 4+4? As opposed to the work being done by the caller of that method?

Yes, the worker does that. Otherwise this would be pretty nonsensical. You're passing two arguments (`4` and `4`) to the Celery system which passes them on to the worker, which does the actual work, in this case addition.

> If the answer to 3 is yes, then how does Celery know it has to do some work? All we're doing is - importing a method from the module we wrote and call that method. How does control get passed to the Celery worker?

Again, the `@app.task` decorator abstracts a lot of magic here. This decorator registers the function with the celery worker pool. It also adds magic properties to the same method that allow you to *call* that function in the celery worker pool, namely `delay`. Imagine this instead:

```
def foo(): pass
celery.register_worker('foo', foo)
celery.call('foo')
```

The decorator is essentially just doing that, just without you having to repeatedly write `foo` in various ways. It's using the function itself as identifier for you, purely as syntactic sugar so you don't have to distinguish much between `foo()` and `'foo'` in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally, is this information documented somewhere? How could I have known that the decorator registers the function with the celery worker pool?

Comment: Well, it's sort of all documented in the documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html. Maybe not as concisely and technical, but you could always read the source code for the details.

Comment: Is that how you knew about this? You've read the source code?

Comment: To be honest I mostly skimmed the description and extrapolated from my experience with decorators, message queues and programming in general. :P